# MySQL Limiting Varchar Select

Tags: mysql, database

I'm not sure what command I am searching for so it was impossible for me to find it on Google since the closest thing I could find was limiting the amount of rows returned.

I have a table of zip codes and some are 5 characters (12345) and some are the longer 5 characters -dash- 4 characters (12345-1234). I want to select all zip codes so that the length is limited to 5 characters (they all look like 12345).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(zip, 1, 5) AS zip FROM yourtable
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae5ef/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTRING(zipcode,1,5) as zip_code from zipcode_table;
```